# TypeScript 2.0 throws errors from excluded files?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have a nodeJS project based on [this](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter) seed project. It has two **tsconfig.json** files which look like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules"
    ]
}
```

however, despite the exclude node_modules, I get loads of errors, some of which I've shown below. This has occured since I started using the new `npm i @types/xyz` approach.

> [0] node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(21,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
>
> [0] node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(85,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'name' must have identical modifiers.
>
> [0] node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(145,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.unscopables]' must be of type '{ copyWithin: boolean; entries: boolean; fill: boolean; find: boolean; findIndex: boolean; keys: ...', but here has type 'any'.
>
> [0] node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(262,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'flags' must have identical modifiers.
>
> [0] node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(276,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'EPSILON' must have identical modifiers.
>
> [0] node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(311,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER' must have identical modifiers.

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this issue after upgrading to ts2.0 with an anguler2 project.
I'm using `typings` for now and have a lot of dependencies. At least on of them is including @types, which duplicates some of the imports. But they are required, I can't just delete the folder / dependency (like other have suggested).

On here I found a pointer to the solution which helped me:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11257

Sample from lucassp:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "types": []
    },
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I simply had to add `"types": []` to the tsconfig.json file, which makes it include none of the types in @types (since all of them are managed by typings currently).

Here's the description of the compiler option [from the doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

```
--types string[]
List of names of type definitions to include. See @types, –typeRoots and –types for more details.
```

Microsoft seems to think that @types is the new black typescript definition imports. Read more info on this [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).

Eventually I might migrate, but I'll let the dust settle, first.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same errors. I am not using the explicit `@types/*` declarations. However, it looks like updating packages have added those as dependencies.

I got those errors to disappear by **removing entries from `typings.json`**. Basically, any declaration that is is under `node_modules/@types/` should **not** be duplicated in `typings.json`.

Don't forget to run `typings prune` after updating your `typings.json` file so extra typings are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the **Duplicate identifier** problem before with my project. What I did by accident was I installed a package in a subdirectory of my project via npm. I had to delete the generated subdirectory of `node_modules` there to fix it.

Also your errors seem similar to this post I found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2106)

The poster suggests the following:

> removing @types/core-js from package.json, deleting node_modules and npm installing solved this issue.

Comment: @types/core-js is a dependency of something else... I am getting the issues on my CI, so I don't think there is anything there not in my package.json

Answer (score 0):

I had all sorted of similar issues; but I removed the whole Typescript folder from %localappdata%\Microsoft\Typescript

Then, I ran:

```
npm install -g typescript@2.1
```

And it magically all started working again...

I did also restart VS2017 several times, and remove my solution node_modules several times...... These helped my frustration, but did not provide a solution.