# Typescript compiler suddenly started to generate errors

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm working on an Angular 2 project and all of a sudden I have started to get lots and lots of errors when I try and run the typescript compiler. Can anybody please advise on where to start searching? I have not knowingly changed anything fundamental and even when I clone a fresh copy from the repository the errors persist. The errors are below:

```
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(102,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'BufferEncoding'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(256,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'errno' must be of type 'number', but here has type 'string'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(263,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EventEmitter'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(549,26): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Buffer'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(549,50): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'SlowBuffer'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(570,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EventEmitter'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(570,18): error TS2415: Class 'EventEmitter' incorrectly extends base class 'NodeJS.EventEmitter'.
  Types of property 'eventNames' are incompatible.
    Type '() => (string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type '() => string[]'.
      Type '(string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
        Type 'string | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(733,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Agent'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(788,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'addressType' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'number | "udp4" | "udp6"'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(791,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Worker'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(1377,17): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CompleterResult'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(1414,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Script'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2550,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TLSSocket'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2684,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'pfx' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | Buffer[]'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2685,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'key' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | any[] | string[] | Buffer'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2687,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'cert' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2688,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'ca' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2689,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'crl' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | string[]'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2691,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'honorCipherOrder' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'boolean'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2694,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'NPNProtocols' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string[] | Buffer'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2711,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'key' must be of type 'string | Buffer', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2713,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'cert' must be of type 'string | Buffer', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2714,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'ca' must be of type '(string | Buffer)[]', but here has type 'string | Buffer | (string | Buffer)[]'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2953,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'padding' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'number'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2958,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'padding' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'number'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3216,5): error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3299,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3321,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Domain'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3613,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(78,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'BufferEncoding'.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(234,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EventEmitter'.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(516,9): error TS2502: 'BuffType' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(517,9): error TS2502: 'SlowBuffType' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(518,26): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Buffer'.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(518,50): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'SlowBuffer'.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(539,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EventEmitter'.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
  Named property 'addListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
  Named property 'emit' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
  Named property 'on' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
  Named property 'once' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
  Named property 'prependListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
  Named property 'prependOnceListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
  Named property 'removeListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'addListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'emit' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'on' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'once' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'prependListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'prependOnceListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'removeListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'addListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'emit' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'on' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'once' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'prependListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'prependOnceListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
  Named property 'removeListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
  Named property 'addListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
  Named property 'emit' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
  Named property 'on' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
  Named property 'once' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
  Named property 'prependListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
  Named property 'prependOnceListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
  Named property 'removeListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(698,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Agent'.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(743,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Worker'.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(1004,22): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CompleterResult'.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(1044,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Script'.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(1886,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TLSSocket'.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2343,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2365,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Domain'.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2625,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you have the node typings in two places.

node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts

typings/globals/node/index.d.ts

Comment: thanks, spot on. Deleting the @types folder corrected the issue. Although no idea why I have ended up with duplicates.

Comment: Might be a dependency of some other package in the @types folder

Comment: Yes are correct again. Any idea how to prevent the conflict? It would appear @types is a common dependancy.

Comment: @types is the new recommended way to load types for typescript. Can you remove node from the typings folder and use the version at @types?
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

Comment: It seems Typescript 2.x has d.ts for node and other software that it did not have before.  Removing @type folders works.  More info is at http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/03/28/ambient-type-definitions-duplicate-identifier-typescript-fix/

Comment: what a bloody disaster, there was a global node_modules/@types folder on my Mac. cheers pal.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, you seem to have mixed @types (by using typescript2) with typings. Just like me when I upgraded to typescript 2.x. I got exactly the same kind of errors.
I solved by simply adding the types declaration "`types": []` in the compilerOptions in tsconfig. I have described this in more detail here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40627265/333150

This will basically not include any of the types from the @types location, and only use your typings declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the typings.json file will fix this.

A previous version of the Angular Quickstart project included this file. However, when trying to upgrade to the most recent version of Angular, I found that this file is no longer part of Quickstart. It was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/commit/544a2faa30a5be0e72d04dca5eb49d55357b3f2b). Looking over the updates to Quickstart is helpful if you originally based your project off of that code.