# Angular2 Quckstart conflicts with @types

Tags: angular

I started to get a lot of errors when running my typescript compiler as seen at "[Typescript compiler suddenly started to generate errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894240/typescript-compiler-suddenly-started-to-generate-errors/39894293?noredirect=1#comment67081287_39894293)". It appears the conflict is caused by the inclusion of the @types folder as a dependency of certain packages including angular2-select and zone.js. I am using the https://github.com/angular/quickstart as a template.

Any advice on how to resolve the conflict?

Comment: are you using VS?

Comment: I honestly don't know however I appear to have solved the issue, I will post below. What is VS? It is obviously important.

Comment: VS stands for Visual studios

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by updating the contents of typings.json and removed the node entry

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "angular-protractor": "registry:dt/angular-protractor#1.5.0+20160425143459",
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "selenium-webdriver": "registry:dt/selenium-webdriver#2.44.0+20160317120654"
  }
}
```

I then deleted node_modules/ and typings/ folders and ran npm install again.